# Selenium Wait Until New Page Is Loaded, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium

I need to wait until the webpage is loaded after clicking a link. The new page's title is not changed, only the url changed from "something.com" to "something.com/abc". So I can't use

```
 driver.wait(until.titleIs('new title'));.
```

Is there any function I can use?

Comment: Ok I decided to just hardcode a timeout ;X

Answer (score 4):

There are the relevant built-in [`urlIs`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/f9d9671db587a7e07b19065288b8bbb5096d0c94/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.js#L192) and [`urlContains`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/f9d9671db587a7e07b19065288b8bbb5096d0c94/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.js#L211) expected conditions:

```
driver.wait(until.urlIs('url'));
driver.wait(until.urlContains('partOfUrl'));
```

Comment: "TypeError: until.urlContains is not a function"
;<

Comment: @ClaireELi ah, sure, you need to upgrade to the latest selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You can try binding the event to the element that appears.

```
const getElementById = async (id, timeout = 2000) => {
   const el = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id(id)), timeout);
   return await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(el), timeout);
};

someElement = await getElementById("someId");
```